# Laravel 9 edit route with {id} parameter returns Not Found (404) despite being defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Below is an example of the route definition in my routes/web.php file.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\WidgetController;

Route::controller(WidgetController::class)->name('widgets.')->prefix('widgets')->group(function () {
  Route::get('{id}/{slug}', 'show')->name('show');
  Route::get('create', 'create')->name('create')->middleware('auth');
  Route::post('store', 'store')->name('store')->middleware('auth');
  Route::get('{id}/edit', 'edit')->name('edit')->middleware('auth');
  Route::post('update', 'update')->name('update')->middleware('auth');
});
```

All the routes listed work fine except for one.

```
Route::get('{id}/edit', 'edit')->name('edit')->middleware('auth');
```

For whatever reason, it works completely fine when it's written like this:

```
Route::get('{id}', 'edit')->name('edit')->middleware('auth');
```

or this:

```
Route::get('{id}//edit', 'edit')->name('edit')->middleware('auth');
```

With "Route::resource", the default would be the first "edit" route. However, I get a 404 when defining it like that. My associated controller method is written like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
   // Rest of code here
}
```

Could it be that Laravel is mistaking "edit" as a second parameter? But that doesn't really make much sense considering it's the default for the resource method.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting

Route::get('{id}/edit', 'edit')->nam

Above

Route::get('{id}/{slug}'

Since {slug} could be anything it's more then likely getting executed first.  I would suggest putting that last.

Comment: Worked! God, I hate web routes so much. Thanks!